# Cava Packager - created exe not running

Tags: perl, packager

Today I created installer using Cava Packager Perl. I can install the app using the installer that I have created. But the problem is in my system that app is running fine but in other system app is not running. That is its getting installed but app is not running.

Comment: Do you have an error message?  If not, try launching the app from a command prompt window, it may show you an error message when double clicking an app does not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your platform is Windows and the version of windows on which you are running the application is equal to or greater than Windows XP, you can create a diagnostic version of your application that will give full detail of the startup and loading process on the failing machine.

In the Build Options tab of Cava Packager, check the following two options:

1.Package Diagnostic Executable with release

2.Allow Loader Verbose Output in Release Executables.

Create your installer package and install on the failing machine.
In the installed bin directory, assuming your executable is called 'myexecutable' you should run:

diagnostic myexecutable.exe

You should get full details of the loading process and where it fails.

There are two very common reasons for failure when deployed to another machine.

1. A module you are using is linked to a dll that Cava has failed to automatically bundle
2. You are trying to run on Windows 2000 - which isn't supported by Cava.

Note: I'm involved with Cava Packager development.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured out the problem. Its due to absolute path